# Google Maps causes 403 forbidden in local

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps

I use google maps v3 in both front end and admin of my wordpress project. (which is in my local now)

```
1. Front end shows the maps in the simplest way.
2. Admin lets the user click the map and define office location.
```

I saved the javascript file to local (if this might be the problem).

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'gmaps', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/gmaps/gmaps.js', array(), '1.0.0' );
```

All were working well yesterday, today:

```
1. Admin all gone, it sayes "403 forbidden" for all maps.
2. Front end shows maps but outputs many errors...

GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/StaticMapService.GetMapImage?1m2&1i…    
003640&2e1&3u19&4m2&1u400&2u250&5m5&1e0&5sen-GB&6sus&10b1&12b1&token=69746 403 (Forbidden) main.js:44
```

many errors like this initially and after zooming and clicking, all pointing line 44.

It is impossible for me to reach the "daily 25000 limit".

What would the problem be? Should I use api-key?

Thanks for reviewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps has some issues when running on localhost, there was/should be a note in the API Docs

Comment: a link to the source will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When I used the live version, it worked. So I removed the javascript from my local. But I don't know if it's a sustainable solution.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp
```